# how to add sticker in whatsapp from Arraylist

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist, whatsapp

I am making whatsapp sticker app, in this app I retrieved  the stickers from the API, and i got the Arraylist of stickers, But i am unable to add in whats-app.

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList_Sticker;
```

Comment: refer [this](https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/26000226) document. Hope it helps